# Can't access deeply nested objects and arrays in EJS template

Tags: json, express, ejs, traversal

Hello fellow stackers,

I trying to get [the following response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.0d2af891f30943e98907b1419364ea86) to my EJS template.
Currently I have a for-loop which iterates all `campaigns`.

*campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights* **.data**

Just tried this, which works fully and the output is being shown below:

```
<% switch (campaigns.facebook.data[i].status) {
        case 'ACTIVE' : %>
            <div class="ui grid">
              <p><%- JSON.stringify(campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights) %></p>
                ...
```

[image]

**However, while trying to get the .data object I encounter problems**

```
<p><%- JSON.stringify(campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights.data) %></p>
```

[image]

Even while trying `JSON.stringify(campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights.data[0])` doesn't give any luck. What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: You can add a <%console.log(campaigns.facebook.data[i])%> to check your JSON properties , but as i can see in campaigns.facebook.data array not all your JSON objects have insights property.

Answer (score 1):

After adding a conditional statement for checking if the desired object exist, we won't encounter the `undefined error` anymore.

```
<% if (campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights) { %>
     <p><%- JSON.stringify(campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights.data[0]) %></p>
     <%console.log(campaigns.facebook.data[i].insights.data[0])%>
% } %>
```